# Open GL ES - GLM Library and Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, android-ndk, glm-math

I'm trying to import a little C++ Open GL ES framework I wrote for an iOS application into an Android application.
I want to use Android NDK to import this framework.
As the framework will be shared between iOS and Android, I placed it outside the jni folder. I specified the path to the source dir of this framework in my grade file as follow (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Source-Set):

[image]

In this framework I used the GLM library for math operation, but as you could see again from the above screenshot, when I try to compile the project I receive the error:

/Users/chicio/Desktop/SpectralBRDFExplorer/SpectralBRDFExplorer/glm/detail/glm.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'glm/glm.hpp' file not found

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should be a problem in setting up your include directories. The error is clear and self explanatory, what is the problem in trying to set header directories. GLM is one of those libraries that compile without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem by myself.
As stated before, it was a problem in the setup of the include directories.
I made the app compile by specifying in the gradle file the include directories suing the C++ flag -I
Here you can find the complete gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "it.chicio.android.spectralbrdfexplorer"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 22
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName "LibOpenGLJNI"
            toolchain = 'clang'
            stl         = 'gnustl_static'
            CFlags.addAll(['-Wall'])
            cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11','-Wall',
                             '-I' + file('src/main/jni'),
                             '-I' + file('../../SpectralBRDFExplorer'),
                             '-I' + file('../../SpectralBRDFExplorer/lodepng')])
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log', 'GLESv3'])
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source {
                        srcDir "../../SpectralBRDFExplorer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sources {
            main {
                assets {
                    source {
                        srcDir "../../Assets"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```